# Huge database logging of event type rows and ways to optimize it

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, best-practices, partitioning

We have a database that stores events. Events are generated at a 1000 per sec rate. We need to keep these events accessible for some years.
Usual use of these events is selecting some of them from the last 1-2 months.

Each event corresponds to a resource_id (estimated 5000).

Since just keeping all these in one table gets all maintenance and selects quite slow and resource consuming I was thinking on improving it in some ways:

a) separate every resource_id to each table. 5000+ tables. Selects from multiple resource_ids (maximum 100) will need some rewrite and unions or something.
b) separate every day to a different table. unions or something would be required when selects will require data from multiple days.
c) both the above (too extreme I think)
d) partitioning in someway on timestamp index and maybe even resource_id index. Is it worth it? Or "manual" partitioning of above suggestions is better?

The database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: [The manual about partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have something simular, ~5000 events per seconds. Tables are partitioned by month and we store 5 years of data. That gives us a 60 partitions, works fine. It runs on PostgreSQL version 9.1, works better than any older version when using partitions.

[EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) are your best friends to get your queries right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case for rolling partitions (or sliding window partitions). Before redesigning the table in thousands of children tables and rewriting your code please give a try to partitioning, like Erwin already advised.

Some articles:

- [Sliding Window Table Partitioning](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/08/30/Sliding-Window-Table-Partitioning.aspx/) and [Automating Sliding Window Maintenance](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/09/14/Automating-Sliding-Window-Maintenance.aspx/) - rolling partitions explained in SQL Server;
- [Table Partitioning Sliding Window Case](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925002055/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/menzos/archive/2008/06/30/table-partitioning-sliding-window-case.aspx) - MSDN blog, SQL Server flavor;
- [Rolling Time-based Partitions](https://glynndba.blogspot.com/2009/10/rolling-time-based-partitions.html) - MySQL flavor;
- [Self Managing Partition Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20110914074119/http://people.planetpostgresql.org:80/paul/index.php?/archives/3-Self-Managing-Partition-Example.html) - PostgreSQL flavor;
- [Dynamic Daily Table Partitions With Postgres](https://web.archive.org/web/20130419062837/http://www.lephpfacile.com:80/annuaire-rss/5-administration-serveur/24-sgbd/70-planet-postgresql/438794-jared-watkins-what-i-do-dynamic-daily-table-partitions-with-postgres) - PostgreSQL again (actually pearl+pgsql);